# Checkboxlist in hidden DIV

Tags: asp.net

I have a CheckboxList within a DIV.  The DIV appears as a modal popup when a button is clicked.  Then the user checks off any number of items in the checkboxlist and clicks OK.  This hides the div.

once the user clicks the save button on the main form, I need to pass parameters to a stored procedure based on which items in the checkboxlist were clicked, but they are always set to unchecked when I run the save code.  I'd love some thoughts on how to do this properly.

Thanks

JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=txtLANG.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            $("#overlay-back").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                buttons: {
                    OK: function () {
                        GetLanguages();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Save Method in CodeBehind

```
  private void Save()
  {
        List<string> lstItemsChecked = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < chkTopLanguages.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if(chkTopLanguages.Items[i].Selected)
                lstItemsChecked.Add(chkTopLanguages.Items[i].Value);
        }
        //stored proc call
  }

  protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
         Save();
  }
```

ASPX Code for DIV popup and CheckBoxList

```
 <div id="overlay-back" style="display:none;">
  <td rowspan="3" valign="top">
     <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkTopLanguages" TextAlign="Right" runat="server" />
           <br />
     <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOtherLanguages" Text="Other Languages..."></asp:TextBox>
  </td>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you using a javascript function on the OnClick of the save button?

Comment: no, it's an ASP button

Comment: Are any controls dynamically created?

Comment: the CheckBoxList is databound to a dataset, but nothing is created fully dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this happens because the when you close the popup, the controls on the popup are not accessible. I don't know the exact cause but you can create an array variable in javascript. Whenever you check or uncheck a checkbox; with the help of javascript, you modify that variable to what all variables are set or not.

I used modal popup way long back and there was an issue like that only.
This approach might not be optimal but will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the AutoPostBack to false:

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkTopLanguages" TextAlign="Right" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
```

For the CheckBoxList control.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but all items still resulted in .Selected=false, including the 3 I had checked

Comment: Hmmm, maybe when the div is hidden, the values are lost. Have you at the source in a browsers developer tools?